# Get all Embedded Documents within all Documents in a Collection using MongoEngine

Tags: django-rest-framework, mongoengine, embedded-documents, restframeworkmongoengine

I've tried searching the internet for this but can't seem to find anything (sorry if this is in here somewhere).

I'm using Mongoengine with Django and have the following model:

```
class Event(EmbeddedDocument):
    tagged_event = StringField(max_length=255)
    example_event = StringField(max_length=255)
    severity = StringField(max_length=4)
    created_by = StringField(max_length=255)
    created_on = DateTimeField()
    modified_by = StringField(max_length=255)
    modified_on = DateTimeField()

class Definition(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=255)
    description = StringField(max_length=255)
    resolution = StringField(max_length=255)
    events = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Event))
    created_by = StringField(max_length=255)
    created_on = DateTimeField()
    modified_by = StringField(max_length=255)
```

What I want to do is return every "Event" in the collection of Definitions but not the "Definition" in the view.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

****UPDATE****

I've found a work around:

I created the Event as a separate app in Django and set a ReferenceField to the imported Definition from the other app.

In the EventView I set the reference field useing the ID o the definition.

```
class Event(Document):
    tagged_event = StringField(max_length=255)
    example_event = StringField(max_length=255)
    severity = StringField(max_length=4)
    definition = ReferenceField(Definition)
    created_by = StringField(max_length=255)
    created_on = DateTimeField()
    modified_by = StringField(max_length=255)
    modified_on = DateTimeField()
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        data = serializer.data
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        Event.objects.create(tagged_event=data['tagged_event'], example_event=data['example_event'], severity=data['severity'], definition=data['definition'], created_by=data['created_by'], created_on=date, modified_by=data['modified_by'], modified_on=date)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Although I would still like to know if it's possible to filter out all embeeded documents in all documents.